# Automapper projection

Tags: c#, entity-framework, automapper

i have question about Automapper projection. 
I have entity:

```
public class SomeEntity
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public DateTime Date { get; set; }

    public string Price { get; set; }
}
```

And dto:

```
public class SomeDto
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int Month { get; set; }

    public string TotalPrice { get; set; }
}
```

How can I create next projection with automapper

```
  var data = new List<SomeEntity>().AsQueryable()
        .GroupBy(p => new
        {
            p.Date.Month,
            p.Name
        }).Select(p => new
        {
            p.Key.Month,
            p.Key.Name,
            TotalPrice = p.Sum(entity => entity.Price)
        })
       .ToList()
       .Select(p => new SomeDto
        {
            Month = p.Month,
            Name = p.Name, 
            TotalPrice = p.TotalPrice
        });
```

Comment: That is not what AutoMapper is intended for.

Comment: Automapper maps SomeEntity and SomeDto directly ... then you can group the SomeDto after that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't - AutoMapper LINQ projections won't really work with intermediate anonymous types that you've created. In your first Select, you should remove the anonymous type:

```
var data = new List<SomeEntity>().AsQueryable()
    .GroupBy(p => new
    {
        p.Date.Month,
        p.Name
    }).Select(p => new SomeDto
    {
        Month = p.Key.Month,
        Name = p.Key.Name,
        TotalPrice = p.Sum(entity => entity.Price)
    })
   .ToList();
```

Then you don't need the second Select. You're already manually projecting so AutoMapper won't help you there.